# Asterisk ("*") works as ls command

Tags: bash

Can you explain why

```
CHAR=$(printf "\x$(printf %x 42)"); echo $CHAR
```

works as `ls` command in the current directory?

I'm trying to print a character by its decimal ASCII code. "man" what and where do I need to read? Or is there some better way to get the character in decimal code?

I'm trying to get "*" in the output.

Comment: See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: See [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com) and all should become clear....

Answer (score 1):

*Unquoted* variable expansion undergoes word splitting and filename expansion. Quote it.

```
CHAR='*'
echo "$CHAR"
```

> why works as ls command in the current directory?

Because `CHAR` contains a star, unquoted `$CHAR` triggers filename expansion, which replaces it by paths in the current directory. Because it was designed that way.

Comment: It's understandable. I apologise for not revealing the task further

`shuf -n 12 -zre $CHAR`

performs an asterisk.  I've already escaped this in all sorts of ways.

At this

`shuf -n 12 -zre *
shuf -n 12 -zre "*"`

works without any problems.